# Adding multiple times together

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to add some data that is pulled from a database in the format of **HH:MM:SS** I'm trying to get them to add together so if we have 00:00:05 then 00:00:10 so we have 00:00:15

I have attempted both TimeSpan, DateTime but I get the following error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
>
> Object required: 'TimeSpan'
>
> Script Location, line 157

This is the code:

```
    While Not objRS.EOF
  
  activecalls = activecalls + objRS("talkingagents")
  callswaiting = callswaiting + objRS("callswaiting")
  averagetalkingtime = averagetalkingtime + objRS("convavgtalkduration")
  totalqueue = totalqueue + 1
  totalcalls = totalcalls + objRS("totalcalls")
  newWait = objRS("convavgwaitduration")

  
  TimeSpan t1 = TimeSpan.Parse(newWait)
  TimeString FormattedDate = t1.Add(FormattedDate)
  
  timeString = timeString.Add(t1).ToString("dd\.hh\:mm\:ss")
```

Comment: The code you have posted is not [tag:VBScript], it looks more like [tag:VB.Net] syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear with your code but this probably what you are looking for.

```
t1 = CDate("00:00:05")
t2 = CDate("00:00:10")
t3 = t1 + t2
MsgBox Right("00" & Hour(t3), 2) + ":" + Right("00" & Minute(t3), 2) + ":" + Right("00" & Second(t3), 2)
```